# Adjust table width to fit two-page column

Tags: tables, two-column, width

I want to fit my table into a two-column page and I am using a table* package. This is my code:

```
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
(table information)
\end{tabular}
  \label{tab:1}
\end{table*}
```

However, the sentence is too long, so the sentence exceeds the page margin. Would really appreciate if someone could help!
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: you have specified `l` columns which are single line with no line breaking, use `p{3cm}` or whatever width you want.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the  `tabularx` package.

Comment: See also: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144)

Comment: May i know which ' l  ' should i substitute